# how to pass custom liquibase.properties and changelog.xml when liquibase docker is used

Tags: docker, liquibase

I have downloaded liquibase docker image and able to run on my windows. I don't want to use default mounted volume of /liquibase/changelog, instead i want to pass custom C:\Test\liquibase\changelog.sql and C:\Test\liquibase\liquibase.properties.

I tried to follow this link https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-and-docker.html

However, getting an error
"Starting Liquibase at 12:56:26 (version 4.3.3 #52 built at 2021-04-12
17:08+0000) Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file
:/Users/vabese/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/liquibase/changelog/changelog.sql was not found in".

Unable to figure out why it is looking for different path. I also tried passing all parameters, including database details (--url=jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/test  --username=XXX --password=XXX). Still same error.

I tried to validate image by executing
 `"docker inspect liquibase/liquibase"`

2. Command to generate a log
   `"docker run --rm liquibase/liquibase --defaultsFile=liquibase.properties --changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/changelog.xml --url=jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/XX_DB --username=xx --password=xxx --driver=org.postgresql.Driver generateChangeLog"`

`Starting Liquibase at 20:17:56 (version 4.3.3 #52 built at 2021-04-12 17:08+0000) BEST PRACTICE: The changelog generated by diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog should be inspected for correctness and completeness before being deployed. Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/Users/vabese/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/liquibase/changelog/changelog.xml (No such file or directory)`

3. Tried to generate SQL with current configuration of postgres by executing
   `"docker run --rm -v /c/PROJECTS/DOCKER:/liquibase/changelog  liquibase/liquibase --url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx:5432/xxx-test --  defaultsFile=liquibase.properties --  changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/changelog.sql --username=xxx --  password=xxx changelogSyncSQL"`

`Starting Liquibase at 12:56:26 (version 4.3.3 #52 built at 2021-04-12 17:08+0000) Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file C:/Users/vabese/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/liquibase/changelog/changelog.sql was not found in - /liquibase/`

Regardless of any command, it is failing when I try to pass custom .properties and .sql/.xml file. Without docker image (have another instance), I am able to perform all DDL deployments

Comment: Could you share the command you have tried for running liquibase (with passwords and other critical details masked)? It might help to figure out the issue.

Comment: I have added more details about commands i tried and the outcome as well